# Eclipse crashes when I search for some particular words

Tags: eclipse

When I search for a word "initial", Eclipse just dies and closes its window without any notifiactions (though you can see that the list of found entries is being displayed for a moment, then goes crash).

I search with this form:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAobu.png

This bug does not affect, for example, words "init", "initia", "initiall".

Why could it be? That is definitely not a memory overflow issue because of loads of "initials" in my code: search works fine even if I just search for all the entries of letter "a". Should it be bugreported?

**UPD:**

I couldn't find anything in Eclipse Error Log view at the chrash time. Here is the error log from console when I run Eclipse and let it crash:

```
susei@desktop:$ eclipse -debug > ~/eclipse.log
The program 'Eclipse' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 61179 error_code 11 request_code 53 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

The resulting error log in eclipse.log doesn't seem to contain anything interesting except information about my folder structure and files : )

Comment: Please have a look into your Eclipse installation folder. There should be crash logs, because your virtual machine crashed. Post the content of one of them.